# Jira Rest API JQL query

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, webapi, jql

I'm making use of the Jira API with the following call:

`https://site.url/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=PROJECT&updated>=startOfWeek(-1w)`

When I run this, I'm getting over 6000 results. But when I run the jql query of `project = PROJECT AND updated >= startOfWeek(-1w)` inside of my Jira sites search bar, I only get around 60 results.

Is there something I'm missing in my api call that would limit the returned to the data to the above query?

*Edit*
Looking further it appears my call is only bringing back results from my project space and not using the updated query. What should I do so it picks up both?

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in your query. You have used an ampersand instead of the word 'and'. The ampersand is the character used to add query parameters, so you effectively did this query

```
https://site.url/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=PROJECT
```

then Jira just ignored what came after the ampersand, as it didn't know what the parameter '*updated>*' was, or how to make it equal '*startOfWeek(-1)*'

Within the JQL, you must use the word 'and' with spaces before and after, like this:

```
https://site.url/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=PROJECT and updated>=startOfWeek(-1w)
```

Only use ampersands to add other query parameters afterwards, like this:

```
https://site.url/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=PROJECT and updated>=startOfWeek(-1w)&startAt=0&maxResults=500
```

Answer (score 0):

Please send the API as POST method:

API: https://url/rest/api/2/search

Body:

```
{
"jql": "project='project name'&updated>=startOfWeek(-1)"
}
```